Wasserstein bounds of interpolation measures
Assume we are given two densities, $p_0$ and $p_1$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and define (up to the normalization constant) the interpolation $p_t \propto p_0^{1-t} p_1^t$, which interpolates between $p_0$ and $p_1$.
I am looking for bounds of the form (under mild conditions, such as finite second moment of $p_0$ and $p_1$) of $W_2(p_t, p_s) \leq C \vert t - s \vert$, where $W_2$ denotes the Wasserstein-2 distance.
The Wasserstein-2 distance between measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ is defined via $W_2^2(\mu, \nu) = \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu,\nu)} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2d}} \Vert x - y \Vert^2 d\pi(x,y) $, where $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ is the set of all probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^{2d}$ with first marginal $\mu$ and second marginal $\nu$.
If that is not possible, a bound of the form $W_2(p_t, p_s) \leq \int_s^t m(r)dr$ for an $L^1((0,1))$ function $m$ would also be appreciated.

It's good if you put the definition of what assumption you have on densities and the definition of Wasserstein distance to the question.

I will add the definition of the Wasserstein distance. For the densities, this I do not know yet, I am not even sure under which conditions these bounds hold true.

So what do people usually assume? Say $L^2$, $L^1$ or Schawartz, or some Sobolev spaces?

I would guess the mildest assumption is something along the lines of bounded moments. However, I expect more regularity to be needed.This could be in the form of Sobolev regularity of $p_0$ and $p_1$.  Such bounds do hold true by the way for the geodesic paths, see e.g., the book of Ambrosio.

I presume $p_0,p_1$ share the same support? otherwise mass should "jump" infinitely fast whenever vacuum must be filled (either at $t=0^+$ ot $t=1^-$) and this should lead to non-absolute continuity in time (in the $W_2$ distance)
